# Cannot remove/replace/edit css file in Django

Tags: css, django, overriding

I think I'm having a ghost here or maybe I'm to newbie to figure out how to fix the issue. So, in my index.html I'm linking a css file which doesn't exist anymore and when I open the index page Django still renders it. Also, if I try too create it again and styling different it doesn't work nor to link another file, simple don't work, don't wanna recognize it. It's like the old file is saved somewhere and I cannot override it.
Do you have suggestions? I tried everything what came to my mind, even deleted and recreated the db.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try pressing `Ctrl+F5` in your browser?

Comment: A lot of times :) anyway it seems the ghost disappeared. It could have been cookies fault?

Comment: Most likely :) You solved it then?

Comment: And not cookies, cache instead :)

Comment: yep... not me :) Thank you very much for your fast reply :)